# Equation Of A Straight Line Passing Through A Point and Having an Intercept

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems

The question is as follows:

> Find the equation of the straight line passing through $(-2,-7)$ and having intercept of length 3 units between straight lines $4x + 3y = 12$ and $4x + 3y = 3$.

I really didn't understand what they meant by "intercept of length 3 units". Hence, I couldn't proceed with the question.

I have a basic knowledge about the different forms of equations of a straight line, but none of them seemed to fit here.

Help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I agree it is difficult to interpret the question.

If you write the lines in the more useful $y=mx+c$ form you find

$$L_1:=y=-\frac43 x+3$$
and
$$L_2:=y=-\frac{4}{3}x+1.$$

This means that the lines have the same slopes and so are parallel. Also the first cuts at $y=3$ and the second at $y=1$.

I think the "intercept of length three" means that the line we are looking for, $L$, cuts $L_1$ and $L_2$ at points $P_1=L\cap L_1$ and $P_2=L\cap L_2$ such that
$$|P_1P_2|=3.$$

There are a number of ways of finishing this off. Synthetic geometry is probably easiest.

> Remember: Coordinate Geometry is supposed to make Synthetic Geometry
>   easier! You are perfectly entitled to use Synthetic Geometry to make
>   Coordinate Geometry easier also!

Consider the point $R$ on $L_1$ that is found vertically above $P_2$ and the triangle $\Delta (RP_1P_2)$.

We know the angle at $R$ (draw a picture and use the slope of $L_1$).

Using the Sine Rule we can thus find the angle at $P_1$ as $|P_2R|=2$ (why?).

Hence you know all the angles in particular the angle at $P_2$, $\alpha$.

The slope of $L$ is thus 
$$m=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha\right).$$